# Trying to figure our CSS grid for page

Tags: css, css-grid

Trying to figure out why my top container isn't laying out correctly. I'm just getting into CSS Grid.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-haze-v633r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

*Edit*

I found my problem finally, my header container wasn't placed to close at the correct spot. Rookie mistake( That I wish I would stop making)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the .wrapper class then you need to set a max-width in order to follow the rest.

If you are referring to the fact that on top right side you have some empty space is that you have created on grid those areas and they are not being used so instead of

`grid-template-areas: "showcase showcase top-box-a" "showcase showcase top-box-b";`

`grid-template-areas: "showcase showcase" "showcase showcase";`

Even tho be more specific which container if not answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put `div.top-box-a` and `div.top-box-b` out of the `<header>` container because they are now as childs of the `<header>`. Change your html markdown to this:

```
<section class="top-container">
    <header class="showcase">
        <h1>Gaffa Miners</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Repudiandae nihil consequatur aspernatur distinctio porro
            labore!
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Lear More</a>
    </header>
    <div class="top-box top-box-a">
        <h4>My Projects</h4>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, ea!
        </p>
        <a href="" class="btn">Projects</a>
    </div>
    <div class="top-box top-box-b">
        <h4>About Me</h4>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, consectetur.
        </p>
        <a href="" class="btn">About</a>
    </div>
</section>
```